# How to quickly watch security camera video clips?

Tags: video, ftp, camera, vlc

I have an IP camera which records 10s .AVI video clips and uploads to my FTP server once motion is detected (it can't record and upload more than 10s in one clip).
So at the end of the day, I have hundreds of small video clips in my FTP.

I want to quickly fast-forward through them. I tried drag-dropping all videos into VLC, which is fine but it doesn't work well when I increase playback speed to more than 10x.

Can you recommend any specialized software for this task? I prefer free software as this is for home use only.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly specialized but I just put them in a folder in win and set to extra large icons. Then I scroll with middle mouse. It works for me.